# Inquiry about Helicoidal Surface and Tangent Planes

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, geometry, analysis, multivariable-calculus

I'm working on a problem related to a helicoidal surface and the determination of curves and tangent planes. I would like to request guidance and advice on how to approach this problem. Below, I present the exercise statement along with some mathematical developments:

**Parametrized Helicoidal Surface H**

We are given the helicoidal surface H, which is parametrized by the function ${r : (0;+\infty) × [0, 2\pi) → \mathbb{R}^3}$, where $r(s, t) = (t\cos(s), t\sin(s), s)$.

**Part (a): Description of Curves with Fixed (s) and Varying (t)**

The first part of the exercise asks me to describe the curves obtained by keeping (s) fixed and varying $t$. For example, for $s = 0$, $s = \frac{\pi}{4}$, $s = \frac{\pi}{2}$, and $s = \pi$. To address this, I have observed that the coordinates $x$ and $y$ depend on both $t$ and $s$, while the coordinate $z$ depends only on $s$. When $s$ is fixed, the generated curves are simply expanding or contracting circles in the $xy$ plane, while $z$ remains constant (similar to a helical staircase). Is there any other important detail I should consider?

**Part (b): Description of Curves with Fixed $t$ and Varying $s$**

The next part of the exercise asks me to describe the curves obtained by keeping $t$ fixed and varying $s$. For example, for $t = 1$ and $t = 2$. In this case, I have noticed that the coordinates $x$ and $y$ depend on both $t$ and $s$, while the coordinate $z$ depends only on $s$. When $t$ is fixed, the generated curves are straight lines in the $s$ direction, while $x$ and $y) remain constant. Is there any other crucial observation I should take into account?

**Part (c): Calculation of the Tangent Plane at a Specific Point**

The final part of the exercise pertains to calculating the tangent plane $\Pi$ to $H$ at the point $r\left(\frac{\pi}{4}, 2\right)$. To address this, I have considered the need to find the normal vector to the tangent plane, which is obtained from the cross product of the tangent vectors to the curves generated by $r\left(\frac{\pi}{4}, 2\right)$ for $s$ and $t$. However, I would like to know if there is a more efficient approach or if there are specific steps I should follow to calculate this tangent plane.

I greatly appreciate any additional mathematical guidance you can provide regarding these three parts of the exercise. I am eager to better understand how to tackle these challenges in the context of the helicoidal surface and tangent planes. Thank you for your valuable assistance!

Comment: For (a) and (b) you might reconsider your conclusions. For example, if $s$ is fixed, then $\cos s $ and $\sin s$ are also fixed, so do not trace a circle. :)

Comment: thank you so much! Then, when  is fixed, the point (, ) describes a straight line in the plane , since  = cos() and  = sin() are equations of a line. So, for different values of , will you get different straight lines in the -plane?

Comment: Yes, or really, lines in planes _parallel to_ the $(x,y)$-plane.

Comment: Thanks again! I have another question for part b: when  is fixed, do we obtain straight lines in the direction of , as  and  remain unchanged, and only  varies as  changes? And Is what I mentioned in my part c post accurate? Sorry for the questions but I'm having a hard time understanding this problem.

Comment: One general technique is to use a specific value or two. For instance, if $t = 2$, the restriction is $r(s, 2) = (2\cos s, 2\sin s, s)$. Note especially that $x$ and $y$ are not constant. (!) The next question is, "Do I recognize this curve? If not, does any part of it, such as the first two components, look familiar?"

Comment: Thank you for the technique and guidance. Even though I find it challenging to recognize the entire expression, I do acknowledge that the first two components, (2 cos , 2 sin ), describe a circle with a radius of $2$ and centered at the origin of the coordinate system.